Caching in python is working slower than without caching
In a Python program, I have to load a couple of thousands of files. I want to maintain their cache. I am able to create the cache using joblib. But for me, the program loads the data faster if I disable the caching.
Step to run MWE:

For my MWE, you can download my dummy files from Github.
set the paths to dummy file directory and any directory to store cache in the variables  dummy_files_basepath and cache_dir

My MWE:
import os
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import joblib

def __load_file(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
                return filepath, file.read()
    
def _load_files_data(basepath, filenames, enable_cache = False, cache_dir = None):
    if enable_cache:
        memory = joblib.Memory(cache_dir, verbose=0)
        load_file_data = memory.cache(__load_file)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
            data = list(executor.map(lambda filename: load_file_data(os.path.join(basepath, filename)), filenames))
    else:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
            data = list(executor.map(lambda filename: __load_file(os.path.join(basepath, filename)), filenames))

    return data    

class FilesLoader:    
    @classmethod
    def load_files_data(cls, basepath, enable_cache = False, cache_dir = None):
        # find the files with extension .txt
        filenames = os.listdir(basepath)
        filenames = [filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith('.txt')]

        # load the data using multipe threads
        data = _load_files_data(basepath, filenames, enable_cache, cache_dir)            

        return data

####----------------------------------------Sample Run------------------------------------####
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dummy_files_basepath = "SET_PATH_TO_MY_DUMMY_FILES"  
    cache_dir = "SET_ANY_PATH"

    # record the time taken to load the data
    import time
    start = time.time()
    data = FilesLoader.load_files_data(dummy_files_basepath, enable_cache = True, cache_dir = cache_dir)
    print(f"Time taken to load the data: {time.time() - start}")
    print(len(data))
    print(f"First data filepath. {data[0][0]}")

Question: Why accessing data is slower with caching enabled? In this example, I am loading .txt file but in my actual program I have .pkl files

As far as I can tell, joblib.Memory simply writes the value to a file which is retrieves from the file each time. Why are you using joblib when you are using a thread pool anyway? It is really unclear what you were expecting to achieve here because the example is obviously just a toy example.

@juanpa.arrivillaga: I am using joblib to create cache, I am using thread pool to load multiple files in parallel. Ain't both different things? The example that I have provided here, is the same code that I need to use to load around 70,000 .pkl files (roughly several GB data in total). Whenever the program runs, it needs same data. Therefore, I want to make the loading of the data as fast as possible i.e. using multithreading (for parallel loading) and caching (because its same data every time).

OK, let me put it this way, your cache works by writing the results back to a file, and reading from that file again when you use the cache (note, your code never actually uses the cache). In your code without a cache, that doesn't happen, so it will obviously be faster (since it skips that step of caching to disk, but note, even if you did use the cache, you would simply be reading from a file again anyway). I

Put it another way, with cache, each step requires (1) reading from the file, (2) returning the value, (3) writing that return value to a file 4) (Potentially but not actually in your use case) read from the cached file when the function is called again with the same argument. Without a cache, you simply have steps (1) and (2)

And again, taking a step back, the operation you want to cache is reading a file from disk. But you are using disk-based caching. Disk-based caching can be effective  if you are caching a very expensive function such that reading /writing the result back from disk is some small fraction of the time that it would take for the function to run, but in your case, that is precisely what your function does

@juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks for the explanation. After the first run of the program, the program does not need to write cache again (since it's already there). So, from second run onwards, the performance of the program should be "almost"  same with and without caching enabled (because in both cases, we are just reading the files). However, that is not the case. Even after the cache is already created, the program takes significantly longer (almost double, like ca. 8 seconds) with the caching-enabled version. Is that much overhead involved in accessing cached files?
